# JavaScript get the right zero-based index of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An alert should display anchor's zero-based index within a document instead of following the link.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    In my life, I used the following web search engines:<br/>
    <a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br/>
    <a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a><br/>
    <a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js8.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = as.length; i-- >= 0;) {
    as[i].onclick = function() {
      alert(i);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

but I got the index like 1,3,5 not 0,1,2

Comment: I like that Bing isn't even a posible choice!

Comment: It's a question from a recruitment test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/bcjv6suf/):

`alert($('a').index(this));`

P.S. https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector

**Update:** same without jquery (you need use closure for pass argument)

```
function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = as.length; i-- > 0;) {
      as[i].onclick = (function(index) {
          return function() {
              console.log(index);
              return false;
          }}(i));
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9f64y0c/

Comment: Thanks. It works but do you have any idea how I can get the same result by only using JavaScript rather than jQuery?

Comment: this code throws a TypeError exception saying as[i] is undefined. how can this be solved?

Comment: @stdob-- what is ```(i)``` in the very end and why do we need it? Thanks!

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin (i) is the argument for the Immediately Invoked Function Expression [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE ]

Comment: oh, great! thank you. I saw it first time in this example and didn't even know how to google it properly

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin You’re welcome )

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution by adding a `data-index` attribute to the `<a>`.

```
function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    as[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
    as[i].onclick = function () {
      alert(this.getAttribute('data-index'));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what collection you are trying to find the index of for that element.

Using jQuery

Index of instance of `<a>` within all `<a>` in page:

```
var $links = $('a').click(function(event) {    
    alert($links.index(this));
});
```

Index within siblings group

```
<div id="div">
    <a/> 
    <a/>
    <a/>
</div>


$('#div a').click(function(event) {    
        alert($(this)index());
});
```

Index of element within all elements in page

```
$('a').click(function(event) {    
     alert($('*')index(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works but do you have any idea how I can get the same result by only using JavaScript rather than jQuery?

Comment: for which option? Still not clear what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the first one. It works very well. I am just wandering is ir possible to get the same result without using jQuery? Thanks

Comment: try something like `var nodeList = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName('a') );
var test = document.getElementById('test'); var index = nodeList.indexOf(test)`.  Works for `<a id="test">`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    In my life, I used the following web search engines:<br />
    <a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br />
    <a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a><br />
    <a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function registerHandlers() {
        var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
          as[i].onclick = (function() {
            var n = i;
            return function() {
              alert(n);
              return false;
            };
          })();
        }
      }

      registerHandlers();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function registerHandlers() {
            var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
                as[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
                    return function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert(i);
                    }
                })(i));
            }
        }

        registerHandlers();
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Please give some context to your response as it is stated in the documentation [on how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery or exotic properties like `setAttribute` are not necessary. This question is about closures. Also don't forget to prevent the default behaviour, which was part of this practice question at present.

```
function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    const index = i;  // the following anon function closes over this variable
    as[i].onclick = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();   // prevent default behaviour
      alert(index);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to debug this is to change the `var i` to `let i = 0`. let creates its own block scope within the `onclick` function. So, when the value of i is returned from within the `onclick` function scope, the value of i is preserved and gives zero-based index value. Without this, for loop has already run and the value of `i` it returns is the last value, which is 3, even if you click on any link.

```
   function registerHandlers() {
      var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
       for (let i =0; i< as.length; i++) {
           as[i].onclick = function() {
               alert(i);
           return false;
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    as[i].onclick = (function() {
      var n = i;
      return function() {
        alert(n);
        return false;
      };
    })();
  }
}

registerHandlers();
```

```html
In my life, I used the following web search engines:<br />
<a href="//www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a><br />
<a href="//www.altavista.com">AltaVista</a><br />
<a href="//www.google.com">Google</a><br />
```

Comment: or you can just modify the script with: function registerHandlers() {
  var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    as[i].onclick = (
      function(i){
        return function() {
          alert(i); 
          return false;
        }
      }(i)
    )      
  }
}   and u keep the comment on the hmtl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).